# mdadm DegradedArray, is that sofware a problem or hardware defect?

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm, software-raid

On a dedicated server at the hoster i received the email message for all raid arrays md0/md1/md2 :

```
This is an automatically generated mail message from mdadm running on cn.com
> `This is an automatically generated mail message from mdadm running on
> example.com
> 
> A DegradedArray event had been detected on md device /dev/md/2.
> 
> Faithfully yours, etc.
> 
> P.S. The /proc/mdstat file currently contains the following:
> 
> Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5]
> [raid4] [raid10] md2 : active raid1 nvme0n1p3[0]
>       903479616 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]
>       bitmap: 7/7 pages [28KB], 65536KB chunk
> 
> md0 : active raid1 nvme0n1p1[0]
>       33520640 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]
>        md1 : active raid1 nvme0n1p2[0]
>       523264 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]
>        unused devices: <none> `
```

I don't know if this is a raid synchronisation problem or if the hard disk is really defective, I hope a Linux expert can help me.

Two NVME Samsung devices are running as software raid mdadm.

> ```
> $ fdisk -l
> nvme1n1     259:0    0 894.3G  0 disk
> ├─nvme1n1p1 259:2    0    32G  0 part
> ├─nvme1n1p2 259:3    0   512M  0 part
> └─nvme1n1p3 259:4    0 861.8G  0 part
> nvme0n1     259:1    0 894.3G  0 disk
> ├─nvme0n1p1 259:5    0    32G  0 part
> │ └─md0       9:0    0    32G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
> ├─nvme0n1p2 259:6    0   512M  0 part
> │ └─md1       9:1    0   511M  0 raid1 /boot
> └─nvme0n1p3 259:7    0 861.8G  0 part
>   └─md2       9:2    0 861.6G  0 raid1 /
> ```

As you can see from the list, nvme1n1 and its partition are not in the raid group. Apparently, the OS has also recognised nvme1n1.

```
$ dmesg 
[ 7664.380493] pcieport 0000:00:1b.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1b.4
[ 7664.380514] pcieport 0000:00:1b.4: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[ 7664.380795] pcieport 0000:00:1b.4: AER:   device [8086:a32c] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[ 7664.381066] pcieport 0000:00:1b.4: AER:    [ 0] RxErr
[ 7664.780438] pcieport 0000:00:1b.4: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1b.4
[ 7664.780459] pcieport 0000:00:1b.4: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[ 7664.780739] pcieport 0000:00:1b.4: AER:   device [8086:a32c] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[ 7664.781011] pcieport 0000:00:1b.4: AER:    [ 0] RxErr
```

`lspci` shows me the two nvme devices

```
$lspci
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983
```

Checking up mdadm Detail for examble md0.

```
mdadm -D /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Sat Aug  7 19:34:45 2021
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 33520640 (31.97 GiB 34.33 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 33520640 (31.97 GiB 34.33 GB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 1
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Fri Mar  4 17:42:37 2022
             State : clean, degraded
    Active Devices : 1
   Working Devices : 1
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : resync

              Name : rescue:0
              UUID : 2e61cb41:dee3a004:b12de575:72c13ed0
            Events : 46

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0     259        2        0      active sync   /dev/nvme0n1p1
       -       0        0        1      removed
```

Here i don't see the device /dev/nvme1n1p1.
What does it means for me ?

my mdadm.conf file

```
# mdadm.conf
#
# !NB! Run update-initramfs -u after updating this file.
# !NB! This will ensure that initramfs has an uptodate copy.
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

# by default (built-in), scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) and all
# containers for MD superblocks. alternatively, specify devices to scan, using
# wildcards if desired.
#DEVICE partitions containers

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR root

# definitions of existing MD arrays
ARRAY /dev/md/0  metadata=1.2 UUID=2e61cb41:dee3a004:b12de575:72c13ed0 name=rescue:0
ARRAY /dev/md/1  metadata=1.2 UUID=455ba7de:599eb665:202c1fe8:33c709f4 name=rescue:1
ARRAY /dev/md/2  metadata=1.2 UUID=c1f88478:e4ed5e8d:56f296cc:38e97b8c name=rescue:2
ARRAY /dev/md/0  metadata=1.2 UUID=e8c8f0cb:91007124:62e03226:94a707dc name=rescue:0
ARRAY /dev/md/1  metadata=1.2 UUID=a335efb7:cc52634c:3221294c:e7feb748 name=rescue:1
ARRAY /dev/md/2  metadata=1.2 UUID=f2a13b49:17f5e812:8e7c5adf:3114a929 name=rescue:2

# This configuration was auto-generated on Sat, 07 Aug 2021 19:35:14 +0200 by mkconf
```

i hope you can help me

Comment: do you have mdadm --examine for the missing disks? it should show when it was dropped from the array (update time) and then you can check your logs for that time window. pcie error sounds like hardware issue. your mdadm.conf looks weird (duplicate entries, overspecific entries, you only need UUID= not any of the other conditions) but that should not cause raid to degrade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a hardware level failure. Since it's a hosted server, have the supplier to replace the faulty device. Don't bother to try and fix it, just get it swapped out. That's what you pay for.

- You will need to schedule downtime with the hosting provider
- Make sure they are 100% sure which disk device is faulty (I've had a good disk swapped out on me once before, from a supplier that should have known better. Fortunately I was running RAID6 and could cope with the second "failure")
- If you can, take a backup anyway "just in case" it all goes wrong. You should be taking backups anyway so take this extra one